# Latest 2.7.2 Ruby version didn't installed at MacOs Catalina

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos-catalina

Could somebody tell me how to install the latest version of Ruby? I've done

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.7.2
rbenv global 2.7.2
ruby -v
```

Besides while I'm running `ruby -v`:

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
```

Instead of 2.7.2. What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: Are you in a project folder and have still another version configured in a `.ruby-version` file or an `RBENV_VERSION` env variable?

Comment: I've seen `2.4.3` ver in `.ruby-version`, besides while running from the project folder `ruby -v` I still get `2.6.3p62`. Maybe I miss something? @spickermann

Answer (score 0):

Try `which ruby` and see what comes up. If it's the system ruby and not the rbenv one, you need to add this to your profile:

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"`